# Unfair Use Of Moderator Tools The Sequal

Tags: discussion

OK so, since when is a moderator’s judgement of whether an answer is right or wrong, a reason to delete it?

In this answer, https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/342672/139766, the moderator deleted it because he decided that I had already mentioned some of the answer in a comment, despite the fact that the answer detailed far more than my original comment.

I understand, from the moderator’s comments, that he believes what I am saying is a non-issue, which is fine, and he may be correct, but since when does that give the moderator the right to judge answers, and delete them based on personal opinion?

I might understand it if it was marked down a few times... maybe... but not in this case.

Comment: FWIW if I expand a comment into an answer post, I usually just go back and delete the comment to avoid this criticism.

Comment: It's an answer, but not an answer to the question asked. It's borderline a comment, and I'd be tempted to flag as a non answer. And downvote. Sometimes we/ the community allows extended comments as an answer, but your answer barely fits as that

Comment: @ThePhoton I would have, had my answer not been deleted before I got the chance.

Answer (score -6):

It is a non-answer, something that moderators delete (or convert to comments) all the time. Since you already had made the same statement as a comment, I simply deleted it.

Note that the actual question is *"How do I do Ethernet/USB on a microcontroller?"*, NOT *"Is doing sustained data logging on a Windows PC a good idea?"*

You might be addressing an X-Y problem, but that's exactly what comments are for.

Comment: Sorry Dave, but that is your opinion. Alternative solutions are always a valid answer in here last I checked, and we are always being reminded not to answer in comments since they get migrated all the time. The whole point of my answer is the user could spend months developing a hardware interface only to find out Windows won't keep up and he loses his data anyway, which, in MY OPINION, is a valid point that he needs to investigate before going down that road.

Comment: Further: Your assertion that the question is "How do I do Ethernet/USB on a microcontroller?" is what you are interpreting to be the question..... it actually asks no such thing. The question was "Are there any other more quick 'n dirty ways of achieving this speed?"

Comment: @Dave, It's pretty common, if we think we have figured out the "X", to go ahead and answer an XY question with an explanation of X.